# Async chai assertion on supertest response

Tags: javascript, testing, bdd, chai, supertest

I am using Superagent (working with promises with Async/Await) and want to do some extra assertions with Chai's Expect on the response. The problem is when an assertion on response requires any async operation, we could not perform it in the response assertion format like:

```js
it('should check for something on response', async () => {
  await superagent(app)
    .expect(200)
    .expect(res => {
      chai.expect(res.body).to.have.property('something')
    })
})
```

So adding async assertions to above will be like:

```js
it('should check for something async on response', async () => {
  await superagent(app)
    .expect(200)
    .expect(async res => {
      chai.expect(await checkForSmth(res.body)).to.be.true
    })
})
```

Which **does not work** and always passes, and when the test should fail it will result in unhandled promise rejection warnings!

Answer (score 0):

Per documentation if the function inside `.expect` returns without an exception, it is considered a passed assertion.

Providing an async function to `.expect` means returning a promise immediately, and it doesn't matter if it throws afterwards, so it'll pass.

The solution is to do the extra assertion yourself outside of Superagent's `.expect`, using the return value of the Superagent's call. something like:

```js
it('should check for something async after getting the response', async () => {
  const res = await superagent(app)
    .expect(200)
  chai.expect(await checkForSmth(res.body)).to.be.true
})
```